# How do I push a right float up, if its HTML is after the content's?

Tags: css, layout, css-float, responsive-design

I have a mostly fixed 2-column layout:

- 1st column that takes as much space as it needs
- and the 2nd column that has a fixed width and is floated to the right

I want to make it a responsive design, so in smaller screen sizes, the 2nd column ends below the 1st column. This means that the HTML for the 2nd column has to be after the 1st column.

My problem is that I can't seem to float the right column properly when using that mark-up. It ends up floated, but is below the main content.

Here's a sample code:

HTML:

```
<div class='content'>
    sdaohdosahdaf
    <br />adfafhaskldjs sgdafadkfjas
    <br />saodfhdpaofa]sdoas [fdf asfasfjasfdkasfad;sdlafa dfasds dad gad</div>
<div class='sidebar'>
    daobfhaohfasod agsdjfa
    <br />sidjaofhad
    <br />sojghfadpfjas
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin-right: 120px;
}
.sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zinkkrysty/U3fA8/

I tried also using negative margins, but can't seem to do it.

If you have any other approaches to my problem (except setting a width on the first column), please give it a go

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put them into a parent and set the position of the side bar as absolute, then use a different set of styles for the responsive display

**html**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class='content'>
        sdaohdosahdaf
        <br />adfafhaskldjs sgdafadkfjas
        <br />saodfhdpaofa]sdoas [fdf asfasfjasfdkasfad;sdlafa dfasds dad gad
    </div>
    <div class='sidebar'>
        daobf haohf asod agsdjfa
        <br />sidja ofhad
        <br />sojgh fadpfjas
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}
.content {
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin-right: 120px;
}
.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
/* Responsive bit */
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .content {
        background-color: orange;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    .sidebar {
        background-color: red;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/U3fA8/4/)

Comment: Yeah.. that's right, I forgot about absolute & relative ;) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Let the **first div** have a `position:absolute;` and with `left:0px;` and the desired `right` you can have a fixed floated right div with a dynamic floated left div.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/amEDc/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <div id="leftDiv">
    </div>
    <div id="rightDiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parentDiv
{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#leftDiv
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    right:200px; //Increase it if you want a little space between the 2 divs.
    min-height:200px; // or bottom:0px; if you want a dynamic height
}
#rightDiv
{
    width:200px;
    float:right;
    min-height:200px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/amEDc/)

Comment: Interesting approach, though my parent won't stretch its height to the first column (which is usually the largest)

Answer (score 2):

Try negative margins in %

E.g. margin-top: -10%;

Answer (score 1):

Try like below... it will help you...

```
.content {
    background-color: lightblue;
    float: left;
}
.sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

I think you needed like this... Try the updated Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/U3fA8/1/

Comment: float: left without specifiying a width is not recommended, because the rendering behaviour is unpredictable

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your fiddle **JUST ADD margin-top:-60px;** in your .sidebar css and it will move up. Your css will look like this:

```
.content {
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin-right: 120px;
}
.sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 120px;
    margin-top:-60px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Comment: That only works if the first column is fixed height (which is not in my case)

Answer (score 0):

Building on [@9205892](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2985029/9205892)'s insight that you need another wrapper `div`, I've found that you avoid using absolute positioning (which can create problems with any content after the two columns), and still getting a responsive design.  Just set the two sections to "float" and specify their widths (I just gave them percentages).  Then in the responsive `@media` section, set the width of each section to 100% and the browser will put them one after the other.

#### HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class='content'>
    sdaohdosahdaf
    <br />adfafhaskldjs sgdafadkfjas
    <br />saodfhdpaofa]sdoas [fdf asfasfjasfdkasfad;sdlafa dfasds dad gad
  </div>
  <div class='sidebar'>
    daobf haohf asod agsdjfa
    <br />sidja ofhad
    <br />sojgh fadpfjas
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.content {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}
.sidebar {
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 40%; /* 100% - .content.width */
    float: left;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

/* Responsive bit*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .content {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 100%; /* Leave no room for sidebar */
  }
   .sidebar {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%; /* Sidebar is puffed up */
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/U3fA8/34/) (based on the demos from the other answers)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to swap your content and sidebar div.

Instead of

```
<div class='content'>
    sdaohdosahdaf
    <br />adfafhaskldjs sgdafadkfjas
    <br />saodfhdpaofa]sdoas [fdf asfasfjasfdkasfad;sdlafa dfasds dad gad</div>
<div class='sidebar'>
    daobfhaohfasod agsdjfa
    <br />sidjaofhad
    <br />sojghfadpfjas
</div>
```

You do:

```
<div class='sidebar'>
    daobfhaohfasod agsdjfa
    <br />sidjaofhad
    <br />sojghfadpfjas
</div>
<div class='content'>
    sdaohdosahdaf
    <br />adfafhaskldjs sgdafadkfjas
    <br />saodfhdpaofa]sdoas [fdf asfasfjasfdkasfad;sdlafa dfasds dad gad</div>
```

Your css stays the same. Here's how it looks like, exactly what you're looking for :)

http://jsfiddle.net/j1wu/vg08f4ep/